# $F'(x) = f(x)$, but that's not working for me, help?

Tags: integration, functions, definite-integrals

I'm working in an online class that's reviewing the usage of $F'(x)$, and I was just given the equation $F(x) = \int_x^1(\sqrt{1+t^2}\,dt$, what is $F'(1)$. Knowing that $F'(x) = f(x)$, I solved $f(1)$ getting $\sqrt2$ but the system says I was incorrect. Was I, and if so, where?

Comment: What is $f(x)$? And is the LHS of the integral supposed to be $F(x)$ instead of $F'(x)$?

Comment: f(x) is the sqrt function inside the integral, the system wants me to find F'(1) given the integral equation denoted by F(x)

Comment: @Andrew D. Hwang, I realize that. I just commented before the post was edited.

Answer (score 7):

From
$$
F(x)= \int_x^1\sqrt{1+t^2}\:dt, \quad x \in \mathbb{R},
$$ one gets
$$
F'(x)=\left(\color{red}{-}\int_1^x\sqrt{1+t^2}\:dt\right)'=\color{red}{-}\sqrt{1+x^2}
$$ giving

> $$
> F'(1)=-\sqrt{2}.
> $$

Answer (score 2):

$$F(x)=\int_x^1\sqrt{1+t^2}dt$$
or
$$F(x)=\int_x^1f(t)dt$$
Note that if,
$$F(x)=\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)}f(t)dt$$
then
$$F'(x)=f(h(x))h'(x)-f(g(x))g'(x)$$
So, here,
$$F'(x)=f(1)\frac{d1}{dx}-f(x)\frac{dx}{dx}=-f(x)$$
Thus,
$$F'(1)=-f(1)=-\sqrt2$$